# Icon for Up in action bar in Android is an arrow (<-) instead of a arrow head (<)

Tags: android

I have enabled the up button by calling setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled on getSupportActionBar(). But the icon showing in the action bar is not good compared to the default one. 
An arrow icon is appearing as back/up button in the action bar, I was expecting a arrow head only for button default. All the examples in web are showing array head for back /up button.

How to make the icon just arrow head ?

[image: Please check the up button]

Comment: In latest sdk up indicator icon is changed to this icon. so if you want to display your custom arrow then you need to use actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.your_icon); method

Answer (score 1):

You can change the action bar navigation icon by the below method

```
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.your_icon);
```

Comment: But if I can use the default icon it will be easier for me ?

Comment: There is no default icon for that..You have to use your custom icon